# How do I get the ASP.Net MVC Password HTML Helper to show characters as I type?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm using the Password HTML Helper in MVC5 to hide the social security number as it is entered.

```
@Html.Password("s", null, new { @maxlength = 9, autocomplete = "off" })
```

The problem I see with it is you just see dots as you type.  Is there any way the helper behavior can be modified to show the characters you are typing in for a second or two then have them transformed to dots?  That behavior would let the user confirm they are typing in the correct character.  If the helper  behavior cannot be modified is there another way to accomplish this?

Comment: Search the web, I found: http://css-tricks.com/better-password-inputs-iphone-style/

Comment: You could use [this plugin - mobilePassword](http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/iOS-Like-Plain-Text-Input-of-Password-with-jQuery-mobilePassword-Plugin/js/jquery.mobilePassword.js)

Comment: This has nothing to do with ASP.NET or the helper. The helper just generates HTML, specifically an input of type, "password". The browser then determines how this HTML element should be rendered and how it should behave.

Answer (score 0):

I found this fiddle maybe you can use this as an option

http://jsfiddle.net/Ngtp7/

```
$(function(){
    $(".showpassword").each(function(index,input) {
        var $input = $(input);
        $('<label class="showpasswordlabel"/>').append(
            $("<input type='checkbox' class='showpasswordcheckbox' />").click(function() {
                var change = $(this).is(":checked") ? "text" : "password";
                var rep = $("<input type='" + change + "' />")
                    .attr("id", $input.attr("id"))
                    .attr("name", $input.attr("name"))
                    .attr('class', $input.attr('class'))
                    .val($input.val())
                    .insertBefore($input);
                $input.remove();
                $input = rep;
             })
        ).append($("<span/>").text("Show password")).insertAfter($input);
    });
});
```

Comment: Nice option but not the answer to the question.